# Replicating Bertrand, Duflo and Mullainathan (2004) "Ignoring Time Series Information" section

Tags: panel-data, econometrics, difference-in-difference

I am trying to replicate Bertrand et al. (2004)'s study, and I am having some troubles understanding what exactly they do in the "Ignoring Time Series Information" section, especially the staggered Diff-in-Diff part.

They write "First, one can regress Yst on state fixed effects, year dummies and any relevant covariates" (Bertrand et al., 2014, p.267). So far so good. Then they write "One can then divide the residuals of the treatment states only into two groups: residuals from years before the laws, and residuals from years after the laws. The estimate of the laws' effect and its standard error can then be obtained from an OLS regression in this two-period panel." (Bertrand et al., 2014, p.267) and this is the part that is not very clear to mean. Do we take *all* the residuals found in the first step and regress them only on the treatment dummy (i.e. the laws' dummy) using OLS? Or do we take the residuals *only from the treatment states* and regress them on the treatment dummy using OLS?

Thank you very much for the help!!

---

Bertrand, Marianne, Esther Duflo, and Sendhil Mullainathan. 2004. “How Much Should We Trust Differences-in-Differences Estimates?” Quarterly Journal of Economics 119(1):249–75.